# Build path error after changing jdk compliance level

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

After using quick fix for an error which changed my jdk compliance level to 1.5 (I don't know what it was before) my package with source got changed into folders. So basicly inside the src folder of my project now is a folder called com and inside that a folder called bla bla etc. and now my project gives the build path error "XML format error in '.classpath' file in priject '': Bad format"
Does anyone know what might have happened and how I change this back?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838229/eclipse-how-to-add-an-existing-source-folder) .
Did you change java version manually?if so then maybe you'd have to set classpath env.variables for same.
Normally this error is caused by missing file hence linking error.
one way-around could be to change the .classpath file encoding from UTF-8 to ASCII.or..explicitly add the default JRE library to the project.
Do refresh eclipse in the end.